# Paginação em PHP e PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, paginação

Boa noite, preciso de uma paginação feita em **PHP** e **PostgreSQL**, pesquisei pela internet mas não encontrei nada útil, tentei aplicar um código de PHP/MySQL mas o resultado foi negativo.

> O código que eu utilizei:

```
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 5;
$query = pg_query($dbconn,"select * from my table limit 5 offset $start_from") or die(pg_result_error($dbconn));
$total_query = pg_num_rows($query);
$total_pages = ceil($total_query / 5);
```

> Botões e Links:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."' class=\"textPagina\">".$i."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
    }
```

Comment: bom, se deu negativo pode também informar qual o problema? seria mais útil!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Resolvido.

Segue o código:

```
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 

$records = 10; // altere aqui o numero de registros por pagina

$start_from = ($page-1) * $records;

$qry = pg_query($dbconn,"select count(*) as total from table"); 
$row_sql = pg_fetch_row($qry); 
$total_records = $row_sql[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $records);

$select = pg_query($dbconn,"select * from table limit $records offset $start_from");
```

o resultado do select:

```
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($select )){
    echo $row['col1'].' | '.$row['col2'].' | '.$row['col3'].'<br />';
}
```

os links para mudar de página:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."' class='yourclass'>".$i."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
}
```

Comment: Se resolveu pode aceitar sua própria resposta, Pedro.